# OpenGL Shaders sometimes compile and sometimes not

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm learning OpenGL and when I run the program sometimes works (triangle red) and sometimes not (triangle white and no triangle). I'm compiling it with msvc (cl.exe in the command line) using makefiles.
Here is a simplified version of the program, please tell me if you also get the same strange behaviour.

**Expected Result** (10% of runs)

[image: :D]

**Buggy Results** (90% of runs)

[image: :c]

[image: :c]

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
//Loading the file, I suspect that the shaders sometimes are not loaded properly but I'm not sure.
std::string loadFile(const std::string filepath)
{
    std::ifstream file(filepath.c_str());
    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error loading Shader" << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }
    std::string output = std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    return output;
}
//Just error checking (Probably I should include the shader validation here)
void checkProgramError(GLuint program)
{
    GLint success = 0;
    char infolog[1024] = {};
    glGetProgramiv(program,GL_LINK_STATUS,&success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program,1024,nullptr,infolog);
        std::cerr << infolog << std::endl;
    }
}

void checkShaderError(GLuint shader)
{
    GLint success = 0;
    char infolog[1024] = {};
    glGetShaderiv(shader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader,1024,nullptr,infolog);
        std::cerr << infolog << std::endl;
    }
}
/*
In my folder:
|basicShader.vs
|basicShader.fs
|main.cpp
|makefile
*/
GLuint createProgram(std::string name)
{
    const char* vertex_shader_source = loadFile(name + ".vs").c_str();
    const char* fragment_shader_source = loadFile(name + ".fs").c_str();

    GLuint vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader,1,&vertex_shader_source,nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
    checkShaderError(vertex_shader);

    GLuint fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader,1,&fragment_shader_source,nullptr);
    checkShaderError(fragment_shader);

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program,vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program,fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    checkProgramError(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    return program;
}
int main(int argc,char* argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE,8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE,8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE,8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE,32);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Ventana",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,600,600,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    GLenum error = glewInit();
    if(error != GLEW_OK){
        printf("Error: Problemas al iniciar glew\n");
        printf("Error: %s",glewGetErrorString(error));
    }

    float first_triangle[] = {
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   
    };
    //Create and config mesh
    GLuint VAO,VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(first_triangle),&first_triangle,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    //Load and enable shader
    GLuint program = createProgram("basicShader");
    glUseProgram(program);

    for(bool running = true;running;)
    {   SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) running = false;
        //Clear Screen
        glClearColor(0.0,0.7,0.3,1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Draw mesh
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***basicShader.vs*** (vertex shader)

```c
#version 120
attribute vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos,1.0);
}
```

***basicShader.fs*** (fragment shader)

```c
#version 120

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

***makefile***

```
LIBS=SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib opengl32.lib glu32.lib glew32.lib
CXX=cl 
CFLAGS=/std:c++17 /EHsc /Zi
SOURCES=main.cpp 

all :main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) /Fe:main.exe $(LIBS) /link /subsystem:console
    main.exe
```

If you have BuildTools installed you can get cl.exe in your terminal with this commands:

```
CMD: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
POWERSHELL: cmd.exe /k '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" & powershell'
```

Comment: Why are you calling `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` before `SDL_Init()`?  Why aren't you capturing & checking the return value of `SDL_GL_CreateContext()`?

Comment: Why aren't you querying the vertex attribute location after the shader has linked?  There's no guarantee it'll always be zero.

Comment: @genpfault I've fixed the position of `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` and `SDL_Init()` and does the same, and `SDL_GL_CreateContext()` should be returning a valid context because the clearing works but i'll add it thanks.

Comment: Do you always run the executable from the same directory?  If not, is it possible you have multiple `basicShader.vs` files in different directories at least one of which is causing the problem?

Comment: @G.M. always the same dir

Comment: @genpfault I've tried and still the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You invoke undefimed behavior here:

> ```
> const char* vertex_shader_source = loadFile(name + ".vs").c_str();
> ```

`load_file()` returns `std::string` which is stored in a temporary here, and gets destroyed right after the expression ended, leaving you with a dangling pointer to memory used by a now-destroyed object.

Comment: how I solve it? storing the string in a lvalue first and then assigning to vertex_shader_source? or there is a c++ way to do it?

Comment: that would be one way to do it.